# msgpack taking 20 seconds to deserialize 180mb of data

Tags: rust, msgpack

I'm new to rust & msgpack so thought i'd see if this is expected performance and if there's any significantly faster ways to use this crate. I have a file (it happens to be geolocation data from a maxmind csv database). It's approximately 180mb. I need to be able to deserialise the data as quick as possible and much quicker than a second if possible.

This is roughly what i'm doing, i've stripped all the extraneous stuff.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Record {
    network: String,
    geoname_id: String,
    registered_country_geoname_id: String,
    represented_country_geoname_id: String,
    is_anonymous_proxy: String,
    is_satellite_provider: String,
    postal_code: String,
    latitude: String,
    longitude: String,
    accuracy_radius: String
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let f = File::open("src/ips.csv")?; // maxmind geolite ipv4 database ~180mb
    let mut r = csv::Reader::from_reader(BufReader::new(f));

    let mut records = Vec::new();
    for result in r.deserialize() {
        let record: Record = result?;
        records.push(record);
    }

    let buf = rmp_serde::to_vec(&records).unwrap();

    let now = Instant::now();
    let values: Vec<Record> = rmp_serde::from_read_ref(&buf).unwrap();
    println!("time {}", now.elapsed().as_secs());

    Ok(())
}
```

I also dumped buf into a file to interrogate it. It's ~180mb. Which i thought would be smaller with message pack?

Comment: You'll need to find out which part is slow. Is it the reading from CSV, the processing, or the dumping out?

Comment: @tadman Hi. I'm only timing `Vec<Record> = rmp_serde::from_read_ref(&buf).unwrap()`. Or at least i thought i was.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. You're going to have to dig into what that code's doing to find out more. Do you have enough free memory? If this pushed your machine to swap it'd get slow in a hurry.

Comment: Did you build/run with `--release`?

Comment: @FrancisGagné I wasn't. That gets it down to 2 seconds.